# speedtest and a big lie

Tags: performance

I'm in Tunisia and I have an 2M adsl broadband at an ISP (hexabyte.tn). they provide a speedtest link (speedtest.hexabyte.tn) 
Sometimes I notice that my speed is very low approx 128 or 256 Kbps instead of 2048 kbps.
But that speedtest always get near 2000 kbps, so I tryed to analyze the source code of that page and I found that there is no real test, It maybe just selects a random number near my pre-defined speed in their database.
Please anybody tries that page and tells me the truth.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the test.php file you will see there is a 2Mb comment, they are measuring the time taken to download this server side. I tested it by artificially limiting my own bandwidth and it seemed fairly accurate and certainly not deliberately misleading. While it's possible they are returning false results to only their own customers I think this unlikely. This page is measuring download speeds from their own severs, you are probably seeing slow speeds to servers outside of your ISP's network, this could be due to their own connection being oversubscribed. in [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/hosting-a-public-dedicated-game-server-with-user-authentication) answer I discuss lots of techniques to analyse network speeds which you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use utilities provided by your own ISP for testing the speed of your internet connection. At the best of times these tests will be an inflated value of your true speed since your ISP will most likely host their speed test at a geographic point close to your physical location. Additionally, the test will probably be hosted on the same core network, which will not provide you with a good indication of what speeds are obtained once you pass your ISP's peering point and head onto other networks. For a more accurate test, use a service like [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/): http://www.speedtest.net/

Speedtest will only work for HTTP. If you ISP is performing traffic shaping based on protocol, you'll need to employ some other techniques to accurately gauge your connection speed. However, an HTTP throughput test should be a good start.